# Audit Logs for Automation SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, auditing, audit-log-reports

I want to provide an automatic log report on a daily basis for the managers that should be extracted from the Audit log to track the user(s) activities in SharePoint Online for a specific document library.

So the report should provide the below details:

- User identification;
- Data and hour (UTC/GMT – coordinated universal time based) of the access;
- Files accessed (with data/hour);
- Files downloaded (with data/hour);
- Files uploaded (with data/hour);

Is it possible to integrate with the Audit log, automate the process and extract the needed information?

If so, can please someone provide an example or mention a resource that I can follow to build that? It could be maybe Power Automate or any other way?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution1:

You can use the audit log reports provided with SharePoint to view the data in the audit logs for a site collection. You can sort, filter, and analyze this data to determine who has done what with sites, lists, libraries, content types, list items, and library files in the site collection.

Please refer to:
[View audit log reports](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527)

Solution2:

Check the audit logs in compliance center.

Here's the process for searching the audit log in Microsoft 365.

Step 1: Run an audit log search

Step 2: View the search results

Step 3: Export the search results to a file

For more information you could refer to this official aticle:
[Search the audit log in the compliance center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide)

====================================

As for whether it can be automatically generated, I suggest you go to the Power Auto forum for help to see if there is a feasible method：
[Microsoft Power Automate Community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Power-Automate/ct-p/MPACommunity)

A similar post:
[sharepoint audit logs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/439674/sharepoint-audit-logs-1.html)